# How can I restrict the file types of my Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

How can I restrict the file types of my Google Cloud Storage bucket ?

For example, how do I select a bucket and precise it can only contain jpeg, jpg or png and should refuse any other kind of file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [policy document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#policydocument) conditions for form POSTs. This won't help with other upload mechanisms, however, so you'll have to do that some other way (maybe a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) that does a content type check on upload and deletes violators).

Comment: I am aware of the policy document and already implement protection mechanisms in my POST requests. I am more looking for a solution that executes on the bucket itself, I will check the Cloud Function, but I would have hoped for simple denial of upload From the bucket (not from my server as is currently the case) instead of deletion.

Comment: I don't believe that you can currently apply a bucket-level policy that restricts uploaded content type. Other than form POSTs (which there is a solution for, based on a policy document), do you not have 100% control over the other scenarios that would upload content to your bucket?

Comment: I believe I do, but you can never be certain about such things. Bucket policy would have been the perfect way to protect my data. Thank you for your answer :)